# How can I set path for non-interactive user authenticated using LDAP?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, ldap, pam

On a Mac running OSX 10.7.5, I need to set the PATH for non-interactive users who connect via ssh and are authenticated using LDAP.  It's the same question that was asked (and answered) here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/139426/updating-the-path-for-running-an-command-through-ssh-with-ldap-user-account

but I'm no familiar enough with PAM or LDAP to fully understand the answer.

It looks like I need to:

```
add a line to /etc/pam.d/sshd saying "auth      required    pam_env.so"
create a file named /etc/security/pam_env.conf
```

but the documentation for pam_env.conf is really confusing and I can't tell if I need a DEFAULT or an OVERRIDE value.

Am I right that those are the correct steps?
What is the line I should put into pam_env.conf?

Thanks,
Chris

p.s. I tried putting the line "auth   required   pam_env.so debug" into /etc/pam.d/sshd and I'm not seeing anything in /var/log/system.log that looks like it is coming from pam_env.so.  I also created /etc/security/pam_env.conf and put in it the line "PATH DEFAULT=/usr/fred OVERRIDE=/usr/george" and it had no visible effect on PATH.

p.p.s If I execute:

```
ssh USER@MACHINE echo \$SHELL
```

It says /bin/bash.  If I then log onto MACHINE and add this line to /etc/bashrc:

```
export Test=Fred
```

and return to my machine and execute:

```
ssh USER@MACHINE echo \$Test
```

it returns nothing.  When I log on this way using LDAP, it doesn't execute /etc/bashrc.

p.p.p.s Some additional information that might be important:
On MACHINE there is no local user named USER.  MACHINE has been set up to do LDAP authentication so when I ssh USER@MACHINE, my $HOME is set to /Network/Servers/blah/blah/Users/USER.  If I edit /Network/Servers/blah/blah/Users/USER/.bashrc to set the PATH, it works correctly for me, but it's not a great solution because it means every person who wishes to access this server has to edit their network .bashrc.

Comment: You could use shell initialization files for this. E.g. in case your users have their shell set to be `/bin/bash`, use `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks Sami, I tried it and it was a no-go.  I edited my question to show what happened.

Comment: Well, now that I actually read the manual page instead of relying on my memory, I find it clearly states that only ~/.bashrc is consulted for non-login shells. Sorry for a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of https://askubuntu.com/questions/382485/ssh-how-to-force-execution-of-a-script-etc-sshrc-forcecommand-on .

With the following you can force sourcing `/etc/bashrc` for all SSH logins, interactive or not. This may cause some problems to those users who rely on `/etc/bashrc` not getting executed for non-interactive logins, so proceed with caution (though this is exactly what you're asking for, so you probably know the implications).

First add `ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/sshd_envs` to `/etc/sshd_config`. Then put the following into `/usr/local/bin/sshd_envs`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /etc/bashrc

if [ -n "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ]; then
  eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
else
  exec $SHELL
fi
```

Whatever environment settings you then put into `/etc/bashrc` will get into environment for every SSH login.

Please note that default `/etc/bashrc` for OS/X will exit immediately after evaluating first few lines (because PS1 is not set for non-interactive shells):

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
  return
fi
```

So either comment out these lines or put everything you want to get evaluated for your non-interactive SSH logins before those lines.